# How to remove images and just place colors in place of the images

Tags: html, css

Instead of images, I want to place colors in those spots.

https://jsfiddle.net/rza8v51x/

The images are set in a grid layout, and I want to remove them and add colors.

In place of the images I want to add colors in those spots.

That is all I am trying to do in the code.

Replace the images with colors.

How would this be done?

```
.channel-browser__channels {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(86,95,115,0.5);
    padding-top: 14px;
    margin-top: 24px;
}

.channel-browser__channel-grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 16px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.channel-browser__channel-grid-item {
    position: relative;
}

.content-item-container--aspect-square .horizontal-content-browser__content-item{
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.horizontal-content-browser__content-item .horizontal-content-browser__fallback-image, .horizontal-content-browser__content-item .responsive-image-component {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
}
```

```css
.channel-browser__channels {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(86,95,115,0.5);
    padding-top: 14px;
    margin-top: 24px;
}

.channel-browser__channel-grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 16px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.channel-browser__channel-grid-item {
    position: relative;
}

.content-item-container--aspect-square .horizontal-content-browser__content-item{
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.horizontal-content-browser__content-item .horizontal-content-browser__fallback-image, .horizontal-content-browser__content-item .responsive-image-component {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);

}
```

```html
<div class="channel-browser__channels channel-browser__channel-grid content-item-container content-item-container--aspect-square">

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">
    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">

    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">

    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>


  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">

    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">


    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">


    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">


    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">

    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the entire img tag in between the div tags, and either add a class as I did in the div tags "box-color-red" or what ever you desire to call the class, and style the background: toWhateverColorYouWant; || OR you can delete the text inside the div class and just create your own if you do not need all of those classes that are declared inside of your div classes. Otherwise, keep them, and appropriately name a new class that will style the color of the div, and make sure the spacing inside the class name is space correctly as well.

```css
.channel-browser__channels {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(86,95,115,0.5);
    padding-top: 14px;
    margin-top: 24px;
}

.channel-browser__channel-grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 16px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.channel-browser__channel-grid-item {
    position: relative;
}

.content-item-container--aspect-square .horizontal-content-browser__content-item{
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.horizontal-content-browser__content-item .horizontal-content-browser__fallback-image, .horizontal-content-browser__content-item .responsive-image-component {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);

}

.box-color-red {
      background: red;
      }
      
.box-color-blue {
      background: blue;
      }
 .box-color-yellow {
      background: yellow;
      }
 .box-color-green {
      background: green;
      }
```

```html
<div class="channel-browser__channels channel-browser__channel-grid content-item-container content-item-container--aspect-square">

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible box-color-red">
    </div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible box-color-blue">

   </div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible box-color-yellow">

    </div>


  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible box-color-green">

    </div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">


    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">


    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">


    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">

    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might get you on the right track, but your grid is a mess

```css
.channel-browser__channels {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(86, 95, 115, 0.5);
  padding-top: 14px;
  margin-top: 24px;
}

.channel-browser__channel-grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.channel-browser__channel-grid-item {
  position: relative;
}

.horizontal-content-browser__content-item {
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.content-item--channel {
  height: 280px;
}

.responsive-image-component {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  background-color: red;
}

.content-item--channel::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="channel-browser__channels channel-browser__channel-grid content-item-container content-item-container--aspect-square">

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">
    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x"
      class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">

    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x"
      class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">

    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x"
      class="responsive-image-component"></div>


  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">

    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x"
      class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">


    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x"
      class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">


    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x"
      class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">


    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x"
      class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">

    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x"
      class="responsive-image-component"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a quick solution to add a overlay color for the images without changing the HTML code would be adding a `::after` to the grid item.

```
/*  Added this */
.channel-browser__channel-grid-item::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  /*  Edit color here */
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Further control can be added with this implement to perhaps toggle display between the overlay color and image, depending on the use case.

Example:

```css
 /*  Added this */
 .channel-browser__channel-grid-item::after {
  content: "";  
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  /*  Edit color here */
  background-color: pink;
}

.channel-browser__channels {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(86,95,115,0.5);
    padding-top: 14px;
    margin-top: 24px;
}

.channel-browser__channel-grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 16px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.channel-browser__channel-grid-item {
    position: relative;
}

.content-item-container--aspect-square .horizontal-content-browser__content-item{
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.horizontal-content-browser__content-item .horizontal-content-browser__fallback-image, .horizontal-content-browser__content-item .responsive-image-component {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);

}
```

```html
<div class="channel-browser__channels channel-browser__channel-grid content-item-container content-item-container--aspect-square">

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">
    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">

    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">

    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>


  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">

    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">


    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">


    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">


    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

  <div class="horizontal-content-browser__content-item content-item channel-browser__channel-grid-item content-item--channel visible">

    <img width="280" height="280" src="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=280x280&amp;quality=100" srcset="//cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=560x560&amp;quality=100 2x, //cdn-images.audioaddict.com/8/6/d/e/2/b/86de2baad6357243d57e77e71494624f.jpg?size=840x840&amp;quality=100 3x" class="responsive-image-component"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: If I wanted to change one of the pink squares to a different color, how would I do that?

Comment: @MarySmithJames There is a comment  ` Edit color here` in the CSS code, this shows where the color can be edited. Simply edit the line `background-color: pink` to a different color, perhaps try some common color [names](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp). Hope this will help.

Comment: All the squares are pink here, how do I change 1 of them to a different color?https://jsfiddle.net/7cye4hfu/

Comment: @MarySmithJames It seems that in the shared jsfiddle there are already some colors set. The jsfiddle uses some color classes such as `box-color-red` to add on those `div`, this approach looks fine for me.

Comment: After I added your code in, now none of my buttons are appearing on the screen: https://jsfiddle.net/fxo1qLje/ .cover:hover {
  border: 9px solid blue; Would you be able to edit the jsfiddle to get the buttons to be able to appear?

Comment: @MarySmithJames It seems that this jsfiddle added various content compare to previously posted one, perhaps it would be best to remove the `::after` code from this answer as it no long work with this one. The `::after` code was only for adding a color overlay while the images were still there, as in previously posted example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250144/discussion-between-mary-smith-james-and-john-li).